# bug when appending elements inside jQuery.each

Tags: jquery, append, each

I have a weird problem here.
I use jQuery.each to iterate through an array and add new elements to my DOM; but it seems that there is a problem when using jQuery.append inside jQuery.each : the function works (I can see the new elements in my browser), but the HTML inspector don't show them.

I guess that there is a problem here, the HTML inspector (Chrome) should update the DOM.  I suspect that this brings problems when manipulating my new content with jQuery, too.

**Original function :**

```
function objectBuildImages( object ){
    var images = object.images;
    var img_container = $("<div class='object-images'></div>");


    $.each( images, function( i, path ) { 
        var img = $("<img />", { 
            src:    path,
            class:  'object-image object-image-'+i

        });
        img_container.append(img);

    });

    return img_container;
}

var images_container = objectBuildImages(object);
object_container.append(images_container);
```

So I started debugging.  This simpler code below *does* updates the HTML inspector...

**Debug step 1 :**

```
function objectBuildImages( object ){
    var img_container = $("<div class='object-images'></div>");

    var img = $("<img />", { 
        src:   'test.jpg'
    });
    img_container.append(img);

    return img_container;
}

var images_container = objectBuildImages(object);
object_container.append(images_container);
```

But once I move it inside jQuery each, it doesn't updates the inspector no more.

**Debug step 2 :**

```
function objectBuildImages( object ){
    var images = object.images;
    var img_container = $("<div class='object-images'></div>");

    $.each( images, function( i, path ) { 

        var img = $("<img />", { 
            src:   'test.jpg'
        });
        img_container.append(img);

    });

    return img_container;
}

var images_container = objectBuildImages(object);
object_container.append(images_container);
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what is object_container? you append things to it but it doesn't look like object_container gets appended to the DOM.

Comment: It is, I didn't put it here as my code is quite complex.  But as I said, "the function works (I can see the new elements in my browser), but the HTML inspector don't show them."

Answer (score 0):

and thanks for your reply ! I found out that my problem came from elsewhere (my images object was not well formatted).
Thanks for your help and - can I delete this question ?